# Free bitcoins are real?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core

That's confusing the bitcoins used for marketing are real or not.. like some posted a code in facebook or in social media for free bitcoin so those bitcoin are real or a just marketing, hacking strategies  etc.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what is actually claimed. Anytime someone offers free money you should be extremely cautious, though.

Answer (score 2):

I rather wanted to comment this but since I lack the required reputation I'm answering it. 
If it's through faucets then it's real. If not, it's probably fake.
Moreover, faucets give out reasonable amount bitcoins for free such that the income generated from displaying adverts is more than the payout you'd get per hour or so..

Answer (score 1):

There ain't no such a thing as a free lunch.

If something sounds to be unbelievable it probably is.

Also, Internet is full of scams.